# How to add missing plugins to collectd

Tags: collectd

I have installed [collectd](http://collectd.org/) on my ubuntu machine. 
I would like to enable the redis [plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Redis) , but its not shipped by default with it. Anyone knows how and where can i download that plugin ?

Answer (score 7):

Before you compile collectd, you need to ensure that the redis plugin's [dependency](http://code.google.com/p/credis/) is met, so that the [redis-plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Redis) gets compiled.

```
wget http://credis.googlecode.com/files/credis-0.2.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf credis-0.2.3.tar.gz
cd credis-0.2.3
sudo cp credis-0.2.3/* /usr/include/
cd credis-0.2.3
make
sudo cp -f libcredis.so /usr/lib/
sudo cp -f ./* /usr/include/
```

Now compile collectd:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://collectd.org/files/collectd-5.4.0.tar.gz;
tar -xvf collectd-5.4.0.tar.gz;
cd collectd-5.4.0
./configure &&
```

In the output, ensure that you don't see `libcredis . . . . . . no (credis.h not found)`. Now-

```
make
make install
```

Finally, you need to comment out the following to 'activate' the plugin in collectd's conf-

```
LoadPlugin redis

<Plugin redis>
   <Node example>
      Host "localhost"
      Port "6379"
      Timeout 2000
   </Node>
</Plugin>
```

Now restart collectd for the plugin to work.

Comment: lib64 for 64 bit os: `sudo cp -f libcredis.so /usr/lib64/`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking for how to install plugins with yum...

```
yum list | grep collectd
```

That should give you a list of the plugins that might be missing...

Then, if you wanted to install the plugin for say nginx:

```
yum install collectd-nginx.x86_64 -y
```